# Custom permission for application

Tags: android, permissions

I was recently reading up about custom permission for our application in android.

`uses-permission` is clear. It contains the permission that your application will need in order to access some of user data or device features, etc and to function properly.

Now, we come to `permission` element. It declares permissions that activities or services might require other applications hold in order to use your application's data or logic

Now, say I use permission tag in my application's manifest file such as:

```
<permission android:name="my.pkg.CUST_PER"/>
```

This will imply that my application may have this possible permission.

And enforce that permission using it in my Activity tag like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:permission="my.pkg.CUST_PER">
```

Now, as per my understanding, only applications that have requested my indicated permission will be able to access my application's secured components.

If other app tries to access those components without my custom permission, what will happen? I think it should crash, and will that be seen in logcat as:

```
SecurityException: Missing permission: my.pkg.CUST_PER
```

If so, isn't that a security breach?

How to protect application data in such a circumstance?

Comment: Just wanted to pointed out this vulneralbility: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/02/12/vulnerabilities-custom-permissions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> uses-permission is clear. It contains the permission that your application will need in order to access some of user data or device features, etc and to function properly.

`<uses-permission>` means that your app wishes to hold the permission named in the `<uses-permission>` element. What is defended by that permission is up to other developers. In some cases, it may be defending some things that allow you "to access some of user data or device features".

> This will imply that my application may have this possible permission.

No, it does not. It simply defines a new permission. It does not state that your app, or any other app, has anything else to do with the permission.

> Now, as per my understanding, only applications that have requested my indicated permission will be able to access my application's secured components.

More accurately, only apps with the `<uses-permission>` element could qualify to access the secured component. In addition, as Mr. Orlowski notes, the `protectionLevel` of the `<permission>` indicates if user acceptance is involved (a `protectinoLevel` of `normal` or `dangerous`), if the app needs to be signed by the same signing key as the app that is defending itself with the permission (a `protectionLevel` of `signature`), or if the app needs to be installed on the `/system` partition (a `protectionLevel` of `system`).

> If other app tries to access those components without my custom permission, what will happen? I think it should crash, and will that be seen in logcat as: Requires this permission: my.pkg.CUST_PER

Correct.

> If so, isn't that a security breach?

Not particularly.

> How to protect application data in such a circumstance?

Don't expose it in the first place. The **complete and entire *point*** behind having `android:permission` is because you **want** other apps to have access to the data, subject to user acceptance, signature match, etc. If you do not want other apps to have access to the data, do not export the component. For activities, services, and manifest-registered receivers, this is usually accomplished by not having an `<intent-filter>`. For `<provider>` elements, you will want to manually have the `android:exported` attribute set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to protect application data in such a circumstance?

You should have read **whole** docs as `android:protectionLevel` exists exactly to address this problem and is explained here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel